# JQUERY/PHP HOW TO SUM FILTERED ROW RESULT

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i can filter the rows from a database table..., but can anyone know how to sum a specific row that is being shown when filtered...

sample sql table strucure is like this

ID   |   PARTSNAME    |      PRICE

thank you..,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use aggregate functions....

SUM will solve your needs......

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp

For summing after jquery .filter()

Give a class to all filtered elements and then use

.each() function to access every element and add the value in a local variable.

Comment: thank you sir.., but im using jquery filtering.... and my problem is how to sum all rowes that are being filtered and is visible.., can you help me with that.., thanks a lot

Comment: Check for the edit in the post

Comment: can you sight an example sir.., than you so much..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/45r9x/1/ 
See this

Comment: thank you sir.., can you look at this.., fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bondythegreat/dm4AZ/1/ is it possible to sum it as decimal?

Comment: In which format are you expecting the result in it....?
It seems to be working fine..

Comment: thank you sir.., found out how to place result in decimals ^_^ thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in SQL directly. Here's an example:

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM parts;
```

This will give you the sum of all part prices.